# Character gone, what do I do?

Tags: ios, terraria-mobile

I got on Terraria on my mobile device and I only had one character and my character that I've used was in the slot that I haven't used. When I tried clicking on the one that I have used there wasn't any picture or anything there. I clicked on it and all my stuff was gone and it was still there, I tried getting out of the game and getting back on and I tried turning it off. What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new character in the second slot. This will put the images back in place and fix it. You don't have to keep the character there, so you can just delete the second one. I've had this problem before!